# nltk custom tokenizer and tagger

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Here is my requirement. I want to tokenize and tag a paragraph in such a way that it allows me to achieve following stuffs.

- Should identify date and time in the paragraph and Tag them as DATE and TIME
- Should identify known phrases in the paragraph and Tag them as CUSTOM
- And rest content should be tokenized should be tokenized by the default nltk's word_tokenize and pos_tag functions?

**For example**, following sentense

```
"They all like to go there on 5th November 2010, but I am not interested."
```

should be tagged and tokenized as follows in case of that custom phrase is **"I am not interested"**.

```
[('They', 'PRP'), ('all', 'VBP'), ('like', 'IN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('go', 'VB'), 
('there', 'RB'), ('on', 'IN'), ('5th November 2010', 'DATE'), (',', ','), 
('but', 'CC'), ('I am not interested', 'CUSTOM'), ('.', '.')]
```

**Any suggestions would be useful.**

Comment: how did you approach this problem? I have a similar usecase wherein I need to tag known phrases in different sentences with custom TAGS.

Answer (score 7):

The proper answer is to compile a large dataset tagged in the way you want, then train a machine learned chunker on it. If that's too time-consuming, the easy way is to run the POS tagger and post-process its output using regular expressions. Getting the longest match is the hard part here:

```
s = "They all like to go there on 5th November 2010, but I am not interested."

DATE = re.compile(r'^[1-9][0-9]?(th|st|rd)? (January|...)( [12][0-9][0-9][0-9])?$')

def custom_tagger(sentence):
    tagged = pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))
    phrase = []
    date_found = False

    i = 0
    while i < len(tagged):
        (w,t) = tagged[i]
        phrase.append(w)
        in_date = DATE.match(' '.join(phrase))
        date_found |= bool(in_date)
        if date_found and not in_date:          # end of date found
            yield (' '.join(phrase[:-1]), 'DATE')
            phrase = []
            date_found = False
        elif date_found and i == len(tagged)-1:    # end of date found
            yield (' '.join(phrase), 'DATE')
            return
        else:
            i += 1
            if not in_date:
                yield (w,t)
                phrase = []
```

Todo: expand the `DATE` re, insert code to search for `CUSTOM` phrases, make this more sophisticated by matching POS tags as well as tokens and decide whether `5th` on its own should count as a date. (Probably not, so filter out dates of length one that only contain an ordinal number.)

Answer (score 2):

You should probably do chunking with the nltk.RegexpParser to achieve your objective.

*Reference:
http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch07.html#code-chunker1*

Comment: Updated reference:
https://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#code-chunker1 .
It might be easier to do (some of) the work at the tokenization stage with a custom tokenizer, which is documented here:
https://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html#sec-tokenization